# How to use Jackson to parse JSON from Rest Web Service

Tags: java, rest, jackson

I'm building a simple Java client to call a Rest Web Service.
I would like to use JACKSON to parse JSON response.

So I'm try to build this code:

```
public Object clearF3A(@RequestBody ImportRRData myData){
        try{
            Object RRout = null;

            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://localhost:8080/CustomerDB/webresources/co.com.mazf.ciudad");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;

           

            conn.disconnect();
            return RRout;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }


    }
```

What can I change to use Jackson to parse the response of web service ?

Comment: What you need to do is - get the contents of the Stream into a String, You need to create a POJO that corresponds to the JSON structure that you are expecting, then do something like - `Car car = objectMapper.readValue(carJson, Car.class);` to parse the json data into an object.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create instance of `ObjectMapper` and then use it to parse received json to class you want, like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
YourClass parsed = mapper.readValue(bufferedReader, YourClass.class);
```

You can also use `InputStream` directly:

```
YourClass parsed = mapper.readValue(conn.getInputStream(), YourClass.class);
```